# How to move server action code from old API to new API?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I'm working with Odoo v8 and I've created a server action which is working OK, but to manage that I had to write it in old API, after a lot of attempts of doing it in new API.

This is my code, the one in **old API**, which is working now:

**Python**

```
def open_action_alt_picking_type_views(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    res = {
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'kanban',
        'res_model': 'stock.picking.type',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'current',
    }
    return res
```

**XML**

```
<record id="server_action_alt_picking_type_views" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Picking types</field>
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_stock_picking_type"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = self.open_action_alt_picking_type_views(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids', []), context=context)</field>
</record>
```

And this is one of the attempts in **new API** which is not working:

**Python**

```
@api.model
def open_action_alt_picking_type_views(self):
    res = {
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'kanban',
        'res_model': 'stock.picking.type',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'current',
    }
    return res
```

**XML**

```
<record id="server_action_alt_picking_type_views" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Picking types</field>
    <field name="condition">True</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_stock_picking_type"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = self.open_action_alt_picking_type_views()</field>
</record>
```

I tried with `@api.multi`, with no decorators, adding a `return` before de method call in the XML `code` field, etc.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what "not working means?"

Comment: It does nothing, not even giving an error... you click on the menuitem which calls the server action and it doesn't open any view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to specify the model on the call to the method like so:

```
<field name="code">action = env['stock.picking.type'].open_action_alt_picking_type_views()</field>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lucas, that was the problem! I've edited only the model call because with `get` didn't work.